# Optimal switching between file editors in PyCharm

Tags: python, eclipse, pycharm

I'm coming to PyCharm from Eclipse, and something that is annoying me is how I switch between open files in the editor.

In Eclipse, I had a hotkey set up to open the previous editor. A menu would appear with the files in order of most-to-least recently viewed. If I hit the key once quickly, it would switch to the last file viewed. Whatever I had been working on recently would always be readily available.

In PyCharm, the files are listed in the editor in seemingly random order. Control+left (or right) takes you to the next file in the listing, which may be near a file unrelated in any way. I can use the mouse to select a file, but I'm not used to this, and it makes me stop and think about what the file name was, what module it was in, etc.

Natural, quick, efficient, minimum of thought -- this is what I'm looking for in navigating between open files in the PyCharm editor. Does anyone know of a way I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason the PyCharm question isn't on P.SE is that questions of tooling (IDEs and the like) are often more appropriate on Stack Overflow (see [help/on-topic], second bullet point under not about).  Looking at your SO questions you have a number of PyCharm questions there - is there some reason that you didn't ask this question there?

Comment: Because this question seems more conceptual in scope to me. It's not just about what key combinations are best, but about how best to use the tool.

Comment: @einnocent the question of the programming toolchain (including the way to best use the tool) is off topic on SO and instead appropriate on Stack Overflow.  If you look at the [help center/on-topic] on SO) you will see the third bullet point of what can be asked about here is software tools.  This question doesn't fall into any of the off topic categories on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I'll try to use that site more appropriately in the future. Also, thanks to whoever migrated this question.

Comment: The distinction between P.SE and SO can seem rather nuanced at times, but we really do try to be consistent.  You can see who migrated it by clicking the link below or going to [the url with a noredirect=1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/221545/optimal-switching-between-file-editors-in-pycharm?noredirect=1) as a parameter (which is what the link is).  If anything, our disappointment is that we weren't able to migrate it faster for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl-Tab switches in most-recently-used order (like Alt-Tab for the desktop). Ctrl-E will show recent files.

You should look at Help > Default Keymap Reference, under the navigation heading, for more helpful shortcuts.